# How to add custom spider/download middlewares to scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

How do I put **custom spider middlewares** in my scrapy project?

Let's say I want to put [this](http://snipplr.com/view/67018/middleware-to-avoid-revisiting-already-visited-items/) one. As the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) says, I added

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'myproject.middlewares.IgnoreVisitedItems': 543,}
```

to settings.py and the code from the above link to **`_init_.py` in `spider` folder**.

But I'm getting:

> ImportError: Error loading object 'myproject.middlewares.IgnoreVisitedItems': No module named middlewares

I tried things on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364815/1552570) but it didn;t work.

This is my **project structure**:

[image]

How should I get this custom middleware working? I just need a **generalized method** to get it working, not specifically for this project.

Comment: not enough info, please share your directory structure, something like `tree myproject` on the project parent will do

Comment: @Guy added my project's tree structure. but I just need a generalized way to do that for all **Spider/Downloader Middlewares**

Comment: ok, what file has `IgnoreVisitedItems` class code?

Comment: `_init_.py` in `spider` folder. well actually I don't know where to put it. Googling around for few min, I found that some got it working by putting the `IgnoreVisitedItems`  class in the `_init_.py` file. see **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11364815/1552570)** link.

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seem that your directory structure does not have a file called `middlewares` as you referred in your project settings.py file, moreover, it seem that your project name is `cnn` and not `myproject`.

if this is the case, you'll have to do two things:

1. create middlewares.py file and put IgnoreVisitedItems in it, place it in the same directory as items.py and pipelines.py
2. change you settings `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES` entry to:

   SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'cnn.middlewares.IgnoreVisitedItems': 543,}

EDIT: note however that in most cases scrapy will ignore visited **Requests** by default, unless you'll force it to recrawl them using [Request's dont_filter parameter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

Comment: well, I knew I had put `myproject` everywhere. Still, thanks it worked fine.